# Jquery: on parent hover change part of child image href source

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

Hi I have this piece of html...

```
<a href="alcohol_calculator.php" class="swfselector">
&raquo; Alcohol unit calculator prototype 
 <img class="tab" src="/images/1.png" width="30" height="28" alt="1" />
 <img class="tab" src="/images/2.png" width="30" height="28" alt="2" />
 <img class="tab" src="/images/3.png" width="30" height="28" alt="3" /> 
 <img class="tab" src="/images/5.png" width="30" height="28" alt="5" />
</a>

<a href="bouncing_ball.php" class="swfselector">
&raquo; Bouncing ball animation 
 <img class="tab" src="/images/3.png" width="30" height="28" alt="3" />
</a>
```

using Jquery I want it so that when someone hovers over an "swfselector" class that all the child images with the class tab have an 'o' added to their src... e.g (/images/2o.png or /images/3.png/).

I have this so far but it does nothing and would add the "o" past the ".png" anyway.

```
$('.swfselector').each.hover(function(){
  $(this).find('.tab').attr('src'+'o'); 
});
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you

```
    var done1 = 0;
$('a.swfselector1').live('hover', function() {
    if(done2 != 1){
        $(this).find('.tab').each(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", 
            $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", "o.png"));  
            done1 = 1;
         })
     }
});
var done2 = 0;
$('a.swfselector2').live('hover', function() {
    if(done2 != 1){
        $(this).find('.tab').each(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", 
            $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", "o.png"));  
            done2 = 1;
         })
     }
});
```

Unfortunately, the simplest way I have found to do this is to change the class names of the `a` tags for multiple `a` tags which have hover functions. Basically add a number to the end of the swfselector. Then quickly create a new jQuery event.

If I haven't made this clear enough, take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hart1994/KChrt/2/) jsFiddle which will be easier to understand.

Final Outcome (joint team work with George):

```
$('.swfselector').live('mouseover mouseout', function() {
if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
    $(this).find('.tab').each(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", "o.png")); 
    }) 
} //end of if
    else { 
           $(this).find('.tab').each(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("o.png", ".png")); 
            }) 

    }//end of else

});//end of mouseover/mouseout
```

Comment: Thanks this is working but I will have a lot of these swf selectors on the page (over a hundred)... which means a massive css and js file. Also would I always change done2 to the last events done variable in the if statement? i feel much closer now.

Comment: Yes you do have to change done to the latest number. So like done1, done2... So on so on. I a working on another way atm.

Comment: Just realised dont need to add numbers on the end of swf selector as it only affects the one you hover over anyway. Do you know how I would reverse this on hover out so that it can run again if you hover over different?

Comment: Sorry, I can't get that to work, where you remove the numbers at the end of swfselector. And yes I will try :)

Comment: Cheers mate I took your code and changed a little and this is now working fully:  $('.swfselector').live('mouseover mouseout', function() { if (event.type == 'mouseover') { $(this).find('.tab').each(function() { $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", "o.png")); }) } else { $(this).find('.tab').each(function() { $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("o.png", ".png")); }) } }); `

Comment: That's ok! Works nice, good team work! Glad to help :) Will edit the answer with the final outcome.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$('.swfselector').each.hover(function(){ 
     $(this).find('.tab').each(function() {
          $(this).attr("src", 
               $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", "o.png"));  
     })
});
```

Comment: actually i think you can drop the inner .each by using $(this).find('.tab').attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", "o.png")); but I don't have jQuery set up here to try it out :-(

Comment: Cheers for the input but I can't get this to work, nothing happens :( Whats more IE is giving me a "Object doesn't support this property or method Line: 1 Char: 1 Code: 0" Error

Answer (score 0):

Think this should work:

```
$('.swfselector').each.hover(function(){
  $('img.tab', this).each(function () {
    var src_parts = this.src.split('.');//divide src by '.' symbol

    src_parts[src_parts.length - 2] += 'o';//add 'o' before extension '.'
    this.src = src_parts.join('.');//join back src with 'o'
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but this doesn't seem to be doing anything and also gives me a " "Object doesn't support this property or method" error :(